# How can I prove this cosine equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How to prove that $\cos(90)\cos(\theta)+\sin(90)\sin(\theta)=\sin(\theta)$ ?

Comment: I reformatted your question. Please check to make sure that I didn't change what you are asking.

Answer (score 7):

Just use that
$$\begin{align}
\sin(90) &= 1\\
\cos(90) &= 0
\end{align}
$$
(I assume that by $90$ you mean $90$ degrees).

Answer (score 3):

Note that:

$$\cos(90)\cos(\theta) + \sin(90)\sin(\theta) = \cos(90 - \theta)$$

Then, by the angle sum trig form, we have:

$$\cos(90 - \theta) = \sin(\theta)$$

To show why this is true, consider the usual graph $\cos(\theta)$.  Since it's the even function, $\cos(\theta) = \cos(-\theta)$.  Geometrically, the graphs of $\cos(-\theta)$ and $\cos(\theta)$ are congruent.  Now, if you shift the graph of the function by $90$ degrees or $\frac{\pi}{2}$, then you move the graph of $\cos(-\theta)$ that much units to the right.  Finally, you get the sine graph.

Compare both graphs [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y+%3D+cos%28-x%29+and+y+%3D+cos%2890+-+x%29)

OR

You can simplify $\cos(90)$ and $\sin(90)$ and show that equality holds.  You get the same results.

$$\cos(90)\cos(\theta) + \sin(90)\sin(\theta) = 0 \cdot \cos(\theta) + 1 \cdot \sin(\theta)$$
$$= \sin(\theta)$$